# Pandas: how to calculate time difference in groups by column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZbvD.jpg), followed by 
[this[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOMwP.jpg)

Stkcd stands for stock ids, Trddt is datetime, ss is a 0-1 variable.

Now, for each stock, I want to identify the first entry-time where ss equals 1 for the first time, and the first exist-time where ss equals 0 after the first 1.Then I want to calculate the time difference between the first entry-time and the first exist-time for each stock.

The difficulty for me now is how to identify the first entry-time and the first-exist time. Is there anybody help me with this? I'm really frustrated with this problem.Thank you very much!

Comment: please paste the data and format as code instead of posting images. Saves us some typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Lets say you have the following dataframe:

```
 Stkcd       date  ss
0      1 2018-04-01   0
1      1 2018-04-05   0
2      1 2018-04-06   1
3      1 2018-04-08   0
4      2 2018-12-19   1
5      2 2018-12-20   1
6      2 2018-12-22   0
7      2 2018-12-25   0
```

You can start by finding out when the first entry time is with:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Stkcd').reset_index(drop=True)
df_max = df.groupby('Stkcd',sort=False).agg({'ss':'idxmax'}).rename(columns={'ss':'idx_max'})
indices_max = df_max['idx_max'].values
```

And for the first exit time:

```
df_ = df_max.merge(df, on = 'Stkcd')
df2 = df_.groupby('Stkcd').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.idx_max.unique()[0]:,:])
indices_min = df2.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).groupby('Stkcd').agg({'ss':'idxmin'}).values.ravel()
```

And to get the time difference:

```
final_df = pd.merge(df.loc[indices_max], df.loc[indices_min], on='Stkcd')
final_df.assign(time_diff = final_df.date_y-final_df.date_x)[['Stkcd','time_diff']]

    Stkcd time_diff
0      1    2 days
1      2    3 days
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small `dframe` for testing

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2), 'ss' : 0},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5), 'ss' : 0},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 7), 'ss' : 0},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 2), 'ss' : 1},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 2), 'ss' : 1},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 2), 'ss' : 1},
    {'Stkcd' : 1, 'Trddt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 2), 'ss' : 0},
])
```

And this is the code

```
# change this to the id you need
stock_id = 1

idx_entry = df[(df['Stkcd'] == stock_id) & (df['ss'] == 1)]['Trddt'].idxmin()
idx_exit = df[(df['Stkcd'] == stock_id) & (df['ss'] == 0) & (df.index > idx_entry)]['Trddt'].idxmin()

t_entry = df.loc[idx_entry, 'Trddt']
t_exit = df.loc[idx_exit, 'Trddt']

# the difference in times
print(t_exit - t_entry)
```

For the test above, this is the result

```
150 days 00:00:00
```